# gem install rails output error in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm new to this environment and I'm trying to install rails. I installed ruby and checked using `rvm list` I get ruby-2.0.0-p0 as my current and default. I tried to install rails after installing ruby

```
gem install rails
```

getting errors:

```
ERROR: Loading command :install (LoadError)
       cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR: while executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
       undefined method `invoke_with_build_args` for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: you need openssl.. see this link http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html

Comment: @NickGinanto I typed in `openssl version` and I get `OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012`

Comment: you should have openssl 1.0.1e for ruby 2.0 and up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing openssl there :)

Install the openssl package

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

Remove the Ruby installation you're using

```
rvm remove 2.0.0
```

And finally recompile Ruby with openssl

```
rvm install 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Everything should be working now. Don't forget to:

```
rvm use 2.0.0 --default
```

Comment: I typed in `openssl version` and I get `OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012` doesn't that mean I already have it?

Comment: Nevertheless rvm is complaining about it, follow my steps and let me know if it worked.

Comment: You can run ruby -ropenssl -e "puts :OK" to see if ruby is not having issue to load openssl, probably it will raise an exception. You can check as well if you have meet all the requirements with *rvm requirements*

Comment: I have a quick question, I'm new to this ruby on rails environment. I started learning PHP... anyways, I was wondering how did you know what solution would work out for me? How'd you know to use the line with --with-openssl.... was it just based on experience? Or is there some kind of method within this language that I just haven't discovered?

Comment: Its a common problem based on experience with rvm. If you install rails from the system packages (like apt-get), then you don't have that kind of problem with openssl, but you are limited to ruby 1.8.x, when most people use ruby 1.9.x for production and ruby 2.0 is already released and some people is starting to migrate

Comment: It finally worked for me after updating openssl following this blog post... http://techscienceinterest.blogspot.com/2010/12/compiling-openssl-on-mac-os-x-snow.html

Comment: How about on Windows??

Answer (score 6):

For cool kids who compile from source, I had this issue even though I had OpenSSL installed on my machine with the newest version. It turned out I needed this library still:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Then I just recompiled and everything worked.